Help diagnose rclone beginner mistake
While starting to learn about rclone, I made the mistake of running the following command, as a test, from my Ubuntu home directory:
sudo rclone sync /media/foo/bar .

My assumption was that a new directory called bar would appear, but I know now that rsync would instead be trying to create a copy of the contents of /media/foo/bar at the second directory specified (including by deleting files).
While running, I was lucky to at least be concerned at the amount of warning messages (relating to links within my git working directories), and so I hit CTRL+C to stop.
I came to realise that for my usage requirements, sudo is not required; and I understand that the sync option (which is the option I want) should be used with care, and that the commands second/target directory may have files/directories deleted.
As for now, and after getting rclone working nicely, I realised my earlier experiment had some unwanted side-effects. I first noticed that the .git directories of all of my git repos were gone. Then, that ~/.git-credentials was gone, and that my browser settings and passwords were gone. The basic directory structure seems unchanged.
As I start to recover, can anyone advise as to which files (or directories) I should expect to be missing?

There's no way for us to determine what files would be missing. We don't know what files were there in the first place, nor do we know the order in which things were deleted.
